# Accessing public Instagram content via Instagram API without expiring accesstoken

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

i want to show public contents from instagram related to a specific hashtag (everything works fine with that) but i can't to renew the `access_token` everytime it expires.

> ("do not assume your access_token is valid forever." -
>   https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

To renew it manually is not an option i have to make sure there is a valid `access_token` at ANY time without re-authenticating.

Any ideas or questions? :)

Comment: When I looked at the documentation, they dont seem to provide the refresh token and hence you cannot refresh your access token.

Comment: Can you let me know how you are able to retrieve the public posts for a specific hash tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have one idea, but without API (and `access_token`). You can make requests to the web-version of Instagram with `?__a=1` parameter. I do not know how long it will work but now there is workflow:

1. You want to show public content with hashtag `space`, for example.
2. Add it to url and add GET-parameter `?__a=1`: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/space/?__a=1
3. Make the GET-request. It returns `json` with nodes in `top_posts` (8) and `media` (18). Each node has `owner`, `caption`, number of comments and likes. But the most important part is in `thumbnail_src` and `display_src`.
4. There is `page_info` in `media` object which helps to paginate results. You need `end_cursor` (for example, `J0HWE9rjAAAAF0HWE9qvgAAAFiYA`)
5. Add the value from `end_cursor` to the url: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/space/?__a=1&max_id=J0HWE9rjAAAAF0HWE9qvgAAAFiYA
6. Repeat 3-6 to get newest posts with specific hashtag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This might work now, but i need a stable solution for the future. There might be unannounced changes in future..

Comment: It works for 7 month at least. I think it's quite stable.

Comment: This is not working now for the username. ex : https://www.instagram.com/3mariachisrd/?__a=1

Answer (score 8):

Update to the ?__a=1 url param. This appears to have stopped working with users '/account/?__a=1' endpoints.:( Still works on tags apparently.

Comment: Yep I can confirm this. Shut off in the middle of me working on some software. Thought it was a soft ip ban from instagram but then noticed that it is even giving a 403 access denied response with a proxy and from multiple devices.

Comment: Down here as well. I guess they're closing the holes following the hearing.

Comment: I think this is related to the privacy gate at facebook. But I am not in that topic anymore.

Comment: Is any other way ?

Comment: Omg! is there any other way ??

Answer (score 1):

Instagram shut down their public API. Here's a quick and dirty workaround in PHP:

```
<?php
function getPublicInfo($username) {
    $url     = sprintf("https://www.instagram.com/$username");
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = explode("window._sharedData = ", $content)[1];
    $content = explode(";</script>", $content)[0];
    $data    = json_decode($content, true);
    return $data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0];
}
```

Not sure for how long it's gonna work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49812302/1932946)'s one for Javascript.