# Instagram ?__a=1 url not working anymore & problems with graphql/query to get data

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

### Update 19 April

After a few days using cookie `ig_pr` two days ago is block. Looks like the only way to get the data now is use `sessionid` with a specific value

### Original

I was using instagram ?__a=1 url to read all the post of instagram's users.

A few hours ago there was a change in the response and now doesn't allow me to use `max_id` to paginate.

Before I usually sent a request to

`https://www.instagram.com/{{username}}/?__a=1`

and using the `graphql.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor` in the response I called the same page with a new max_id

`https://www.instagram.com/{{username}}/?__a=1&max_id={{end_cursor}}`

Now the `end_cursor` changes in each call & max_id is not working.

Please help :)

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/{{username}}/?__a=1 doesn't work for me at all and just gives access denied.

Comment: @dprogramz ?__a=1 is not working anymore, please read the solutions where you can extract _sharedData in the normal webpage

Comment: now this url's not working

Comment: "?__a=1" seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The query_hash does not change, at least in the past few days.  It indicate what TYPE of query it is.

Below listed 4 query types I knew, hope these help.

Load more **media** under https://www.instagram.com/someone/?__a=1

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={"id":"93024","first":12,"after":"XXXXXXXX"}
```

(Instagram blocked the above access since 2018-04-12.  You have to remove the __a=1 and extract the JSON inside a  block.  Look for "window._sharedData" in the HTML)

Load more **media** under https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/iphone/?__a=1

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=298b92c8d7cad703f7565aa892ede943&variables={"tag_name":"iphone","first":12,"after":"XXXXXXXX"}
```

Load more **media** under https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/703629436462521/?__a=1

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=ac38b90f0f3981c42092016a37c59bf7&variables={"id":"703629436462521","first":12,"after":"XXXXXXXX"}
```

Load more **comments** for https://www.instagram.com/p/Bf-I2P6grhd/

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=33ba35852cb50da46f5b5e889df7d159&variables={"shortcode":"Bf-I2P6grhd","first":20,"after":"XXXXXXXX"}
```

where XXXXXXXX is the end_cursor from the original request

Comment: do you know the query_hash for load more location for explore/locations api?

Comment: the above query_hash gives ```{ message: 'forbidden', status: 'fail' }``` for my request ```https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=298b92c8d7cad703f7565aa892ede943&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22%3A%22nasa%22%2C%22first%22%3A50%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQB0kona4PHJNMYAdLC4F4vPROUjIH47lawQ2Kx_sbq6KgE8p9hTkJu-V2LlMlzbS5gCZ4Uks3APKeBZ5SCnf9L_ovpvxzJPmYaG0o8EVF5Jgg%22%7D
```

Comment: location query_hash ```query_hash=ac38b90f0f3981c42092016a37c59bf7```

Comment: Your "variables" were wrong.  It is not tag_name=...  you must get the locations id first...  I will update the post soon.

Comment: yes thanks. I have commented the query_hash and was successfull in fetching the API. My api was failing because i havent added any Cookie header in my api request which was not required previously. I added it and now its working fine.

Comment: as of 12 April 2018, only load more apis are failing without Cookie header set

Comment: does anyone know how to get the id of a public page? I used to use a website before, but doesnt work any longer, its not the client id

Comment: What public page you are referring to?

Comment: I figured it out, just found it by opening up chrome and doing window.sharedData ... My issue is even though the json shows up on the browser I can't seem to extract it via the above mention methods

Comment: @NoushadPP: what cookie header set it needs actually? I tried with cookies set but failed. can you please explain, thanks

Comment: @ArbazAbid: what I did is I logged in to my Instagram and loaded some page and in the developer console I checked the networks tab to see the network calls. You can see in every request they are sending a header called Cookie with a variable. So I used that value to make the api calls by setting the same header value pair in the request header. I used only Cookies header and nothing else

Comment: @NoushadPP: I also tried the same, logged in and get cookies and generated cookie set to send request to Instagram but still `403` error. Can you please tell which cookies you used, thanks. I used `csrftoken` `mid` `rur` `ig_or` `ig_pr` `ig_vh` `ig_vw`

Comment: @ArbazAbid you can see my code in the answer below. It seems Instagram has different API authentication processes in different parts of the world. I am not passing any csrftoken or other headers except for the simple `Cookie` header Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786980/instagram-web-scraping-what-am-i-doing-differently-that-makes-my-solution-non-f) will help you

Comment: @NoushadPP: I am able to get JSON now for next page, any experience how many requests It allows before it goes to `429` error limit reached? did you face that issue?

Comment: @ArbazAbid No idea on the API rate limit. Better keep it low so that the API servers won't detect some kind of anomaly on your requests if they have some kind of checks on your requests. How did you manage to get your api to be working?

Comment: @SAURABHRATHOD, seems still works fine for me.  Try another IP?  And never spam their server.

Comment: These only work a hand full of times (like literally up to around 5-10 times) and after that, it will begin to response with the instagram log in page, so you'll have to cache the first time. Maybe use local storage.

Comment: Both FB and IG use similar anti-scraping approach.  If you don't have a valid user session, you can only view few pages / posts.  If you have a valid user session, you can get much much more.  Sure, they will simply lock your account if you scrape too much.  Or, if you don't have a lot of valid session, then, you need a lot of IP (proxy).

Comment: What we use in place of __a=1 in twitter for downloade video and image@FelixNg

Answer (score 32):

Edit 15/03
**NOT WORKING ANYMORE**
Seems like instagram changed again their API, now it gives a CORS error.

As of 2 february 2021, I have found a solution

Instead of using
https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1
which it asks for a login.

Justing adding a /channel seems to make it work, like so:

https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1

Comment: Worked for me also. But when I am using https://www.instagram.com/pawanlakhera77/?__a=1&access_token={mytoken} I am still getting the login page.  Do I need to have instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media for instagram basic display api ? Can't I test this without these permission?

Comment: Thanks for this comment! Helped me out as well. Curious how long it'll work though 

I really wish Instagram could just have a stable public API to view the images of accounts that are public... otherwise people will always resort to scraping or other nonsense

Comment: had to reset my password and login to my account just to upvote your comment. haha thank you!

Comment: Can you please link to a way this can be implemented?

Comment: Is this solution still working for you? I receive also on the /username/channel endpoint a CORS error

Comment: You as of 2-3 days back, CORS issue is being triggered. I am able to do that query from a node environment on my local system, but when I do using a lamda function, I think it is trying to redirect me to login page and thus invalid JSON response.

Comment: I wish they still had this active :( Have you guys found any workarounds?

Comment: this solution works perfectly.
https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1 also not working and ask for login details

Comment: My next question is : how did you figure about the ``/channel`` trick ? I wan't to know how the idea came to your brain like : "Do this, put /channel just before the ?__a=1, and it will work." Still working tho, many thanks !

Comment: Whenever you switch tabs in a instagram profile, from posts to reels for example, the url changes to instagram.com/username/reels, in the post I was using /channel, which is the tab for videos in a profile.  So i noticed instagram was only blocking requests from the default instagram.com/username. But soon after the post they patched it.

Comment: What we use in place of __a=1 in twitter for downloade video and image@MattF

Comment: use `follow_redirect` in your framework to make it work.

Answer (score 26):

i fixed it by adding `&__d=dis`. for example like this `https://www.instagram.com/p/Ch656GRoyuO/?__a=1&__d=dis`

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/p/Ch656GRoyuO/?__a=1&__d=dis



{
  "message": "Please wait a few minutes before trying again.",
  "require_login": true,
  "status": "fail"
}

Comment: add the sessionid cookie for this error

Comment: @IRDN What do you mean?

Comment: NOT WORKING ANYMORE, PATCHED !

Comment: does anoyone know whats working ?

Answer (score 15):

I just came by the same issue.

Looks like they just changed their private api by removing the **max_id**.
Their website seems to have replaced the old api with the graphql api.

> https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={"id":"111","first":12,"after":"xxx"}

- **id**: user ID,
- **first**: amount of nodes to get,
- **after**: the 'end_cursor' you can get from data['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['end_cursor']

use either query_hash or query_id

- **query_hash**: 472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b
- **query_id**: 17888483320059182

I have no idea how long that query_id/query_hash will work, it's up to Instagram. They will eventually change it.

**Updated 4/8/2018** - Before FB didn't check any cookies, but looks like they added quick validation. Try adding `ig_pr=2` to the request cookie, when sending your API. This quick fix works for me. Who knows when FB will change it again.

As long as FB doesn't enforce login for these basic APIs, there always will be an easy workaround.

Comment: I just found the same solution! It's working right now, but looks like we will have to use their API

Comment: @pablo , did you find any solution? I realy need it ;(

Comment: Any body knows what is query_hash?!

Comment: @SalehMosleh That api endpoint is Instagram's private api, created to be used only by Instagram app/web not for public. So probably only Instagram know what query_hash and query_id represents. I first thought it was hashed value of the variables, but it is permanent(independent of variables). Think of it like **hard coded auth_token**.

Comment: seems like it's not working anymore, It's returning JSON by directly loading through the browser but return `(403) Forbidden` in the application.

Comment: @ArbazAbid  I was afraid this would happen. Ever since the Cambridge Analytica fiasco, Facebook has been changing their APIs without notices. We can't really blame them since this API is not meant to be used by end users anyways. Since one of my project depends on this API, I will eventually take a look into it.

Comment: @DanielChoi: Please update here if you see any progress, Thanks

Comment: Yesterday all the request started to fail again I don't receive any response when I call them using an ajax call...

Comment: @Pablo I have updated quick fix above. When sending the request, add `ig_pr=2` to the request cookie. I have a feeling this is gonna be a game of cat and mouse.

Comment: @DanielChoi I was checking this option but I do an ajax call, I set ig_pr cookie before send the request but doesn't work, if i open the navigator and I set it when I directly check the url it's fine but not in the ajax call, because the cookie is from my domain

Comment: Anyone with a solution? ig_pr=2 worked yesterday. Today it doesnt work

Comment: @Pablo ajax is little different due to CORS. Looks like instagram has changed their API AGAIN. so my yesterday's method `ig_pr=2` doesn't work.

Comment: `ig_pr=2` is gone now, any luck how to get next page JSON?

Comment: Does Session object automatically update cookies with all necessary cookies?

Comment: @DanielChoi from where did you find query_hash and query_id, is it documented somewhere?:
query_hash: 472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b
query_id: 17888483320059182

Answer (score 12):

Translated some of the folks' code to PHP:

```
<?php
function getPublicInfo($username) {
    $url     = sprintf("https://www.instagram.com/$username");
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = explode("window._sharedData = ", $content)[1];
    $content = explode(";</script>", $content)[0];
    $data    = json_decode($content, true);
    return $data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0];
}
```

Not sure for how long it's gonna work. For my small project it does the job for now. The result is very similar (if not equal) to the one at the URL: `instagram.com/{user}/?__a=1`

Comment: thank you for sharing this, solved my problem for now

Comment: can we get the mp4 or jpg url of media (picture or video ) using php curl ?

Comment: I don't know how long is gonna work, but so far the "window._sharedData" method works, while the usual "file_get_contents" seems to trigger some kind of black-listing of the request's IP (which, btw, we don't know how long it stays as black-listed or if it's white-listed any time).

Comment: It seems that solution is not working now

Answer (score 8):

The main problem with using graph/query is that I only have the **username**, to extract the userId & the last post like we use to do with ?__a=1 we have to get the instagram's user page & extract _sharedData

**Javascript**

```
let url = "https://www.instagram.com/"+username;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    error: function () {
        //..
    },
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0]).entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql;
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

After get all this data we can call graph/query (not in client side)

Comment: Your data var will not work. You need to escape the closing bracket in the script tag                `data = JSON.parse(data.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";<\/script>")[0]).entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql;`

Comment: @Pablo how i can get first page of my own feeds?  I want get window.__additionalDataLoaded('feed' data! Could you help ? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As of 21 May 2021, using a /channel will make it work, but only if using a browser User-Agent header with your request, for example with a curl:

`curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36" https://www.instagram.com/{username}/channel/?__a=1`

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 5):

For pagination you can now use ?__a=1&page=2

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, but how did you figure this out?

Comment: @Moondra i was just looking into network requests in dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not directly helping the question but posting because someone might benefit from the answer. As of the current date 12 April 2018, the load more APIs will not work without a `Cookie` header set.
Below are some codes for fetching Instagram public APIS

```
    let url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/";
    if (payload.type == 'location') {
        url = url + "locations/" + payload.location_id + "/" + payload.location_name + "/?__a=1";
    } else if (payload.type == 'hashtag') {
        url = url + "tags/" + payload.hashtag + "/?__a=1";
    } else { //profile
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + payload.user_name + "/?__a=1";
    }

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        //below are params which are required for load more pagination payload
        paginationData = {
            has_next_page: body.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page,
            end_cursor: body.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor
        };

        //user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media for profile posts,
        //hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media for hashtag posts
        //location.edge_location_to_media for location posts
    });
```

and for load more items, I am using:

```
    let url = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/";
    if (payload.type == 'location') {
        let variables = encodeURIComponent('{"id":"' + payload.pagination.id + '","first":50,"after":"' + payload.pagination.end_cursor + '"}');
        url = url + "?query_hash=ac38b90f0f3981c42092016a37c59bf7&query_id=17865274345132052&variables=" + variables;
    } else if (payload.type == 'hashtag') {
        let variables = encodeURIComponent('{"tag_name":"' + payload.pagination.tag_name + '","first":50,"after":"' + payload.pagination.end_cursor + '"}');
        url = url + "?query_hash=298b92c8d7cad703f7565aa892ede943&query_id=17875800862117404&variables=" + variables;
    } else { //profile
        let variables = encodeURIComponent('{"id":"' + payload.pagination.owner_id + '","first":50,"after":"' + payload.pagination.end_cursor + '"}');
        url = url + "?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&query_id=17888483320059182&variables=" + variables;
    }

    let options = {
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Cookie: "Cookie value which i copied from my logged in instagram browser window"
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) { });
```

It seems `query_id` is no longer required and `query_hash` is sufficient now. I'm not sure though but it seems working without them too for me.

Comment: How can I get `query_hash` and `query_id` parameter ?

Comment: ```query_hash``` and ```query_id``` are fixed for each type of request. I think query_id is not longer required. query_hash is enough. I just kept it for someones reference. You can use the above values

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me so far, seems there is no rate limits as I have daily 2k+ traffic on my site and this solution is still working fine.

Answer (score 3):

## As of 19th May 2023

The solution that seems to be working fine for me (without using an external website) is to send a request here:

`https://www.instagram.com/{username}/feed/?__a=1&__d=dis`

There is **no need to be authenticated** (and have a session id) to make this request.

The problem I'm still encountering is that I can't get all posts, and I can only get the first 12.

I tried adding `max_id={{end_cursor}}` to the URL but it didn't work.

Comment: Its working in a browser where I have instagram already logged in but not in postman/incognito window. What else does it want?

Comment: somewhere in another post, I was people recommending putting the max_id in between the parameters like this `?__a=1&max_id={{end_cursor}}&__d=dis`
this was the only way for me to work

Answer (score 2):

As of the current date 12 April 2018, 4:00PM (GMT+1), API queries work without any cookie. I have no idea what they're doing...

Just try [this link](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables=%7B%22id%22:%22184263228%22,%22first%22:%2212%22%7D) in private navigation.

Comment: I'm getting 403 error for this without login. I'm from India and I think they have deployed their changed code to a new server and gradually migrating the traffic.

Comment: @FarazAzhar x-requested-with, x-instagram-gis, cookie and user-agent are mandatory in headers.

Comment: where do you get the query_hash from ?

Answer (score 2):

Now it returns this response and doesn't work:

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something
> went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your
> browser
> window.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1006107013}}},"lid":"7136695846284496053"}

URL: https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1

URL: https://www.instagram.com/instagram/channel/?__a=1

Comment: try adding __d=dist to query string it would fix the problem the link would be like this:
URL: [https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1&__d=dist](https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1&__d=dist)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem in that I was unable to parse the JSON file using "**?__a=1**" and ended up with `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`. Searched in many places and finally found a catch, using Header solved the probelm. Try using this, it worked for me

```
link = 'http://instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

100% working as of now
It can be circumvented using the session ID.

- It also works on a never logged in ip.
  I sent 10K queries and it didn't give any errors.
  [Instagram Api Curl Request](https://github.com/crypto-su/instagramProfileApiHack)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

actually the position and tag changed if you look clearly we dont require any channel or anything url change at all the data is present under video versions  attribute with many video quality actually  [image]

but sometimes ?_a=1 working normally i.e you can see the short code in the start

Comment: using ?__a=1 is resulting in 'has been blocked by CORS policy'

Answer (score 0):

Currently https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1 seems to be working. However, after a few minutes of trying this URL, it may still request for login. In this case, if you convert the word channel to reels, the problem will be fixed.

For example:
https://www.instagram.com/username/reels/?__a=1

Comment: Worked for me to some extent. What other endpoint variations are available? For example, `feed/` worked too

Comment: where did you find these endpoint variations ?

Comment: I looked my instagram profile in web browser. Then, I clicked the all pages in profile pages like, reels, channels etc. Finally, I tried this words and it worked. Also, can you try tagged, saved,  followers and follower words? Maybe, It works.