# Instagram scraping after the new changes with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, instagram, http-status-code-403

I've been trying to scrape comments from a bunch of public instagram posts by writing a Python crawler (Scrapy).
I've looked at all the available material, especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786980/how-to-perform-unauthenticated-instagram-web-scraping-in-response-to-recent-priv), but so far I've had no luck. It's worth mentioning that I've also tried making the hash from

> rhx_gis + ":" + csrf_token + ":" + user agent + ":" + variables

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper/issues/210#issuecomment-380437511), but also without luck.

I keep getting 403 responses from the server. At first I thought It was due to my USER_AGENT settings (set to Mozzila 5....) or headers, but I've tested those (I even went ahead, analyzed X-Instagram-GIS of a request made from inside the browser and checked if the MD5 hash matches on my Scrapy request. 
The generated URL works fine inside a browser regardless if I'm logged into IG or not - however, it breaks when used inside an Incognito window, Scrapy or Scrapy shell.

At first I thought it meant that scraping is just not possible, however, the [rarcega](https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper) scraper works just fine (except it's not really handy for scraping individual posts rather than whole user profiles).

Any feedback or thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please compare the sent request from scrapy to the request from rarcega and your browser?