# How to properly payload the session cookies into fetch

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-apps-script, instagram

Recently Instagram API is dramatically changing [Instagram ?__a=1 url doesn't allow max_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265339/instagram-a-1-url-doesnt-allow-max-id/49812302), it requires a proper cookie to make it work.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798846/8326073
>
> As of the current date 12 April 2018, 4:00PM (GMT+1), API queries work without any cookie. I have no idea what they're doing...
>
> Just try this link in private navigation.

So, I made some change to my script by logging in to Instagram using a browser and taken some cookie value. Some part of the code is shown below.

```
var username = "1364162422";
var url = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={\"id\":\"" + username + "\",\"first\":\"16\"}";
var options = {
    "headers" : {
        "Cookie" : {
            "ds_user_id" : "your user id taken from logged in request header from browser such as 123456789",
            "sessionid" : "your session id taken from logged in request header from browser"
            }
        }
    };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```

I got this response code.

```
Invalid argument: https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={"id":"1364162422","first":"16"}
```

I've searched and researched a lot on internet but I can't find a solution to this problem yet. Any suggestion or answer is really appreciated.