# Instagram get posts with hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want my app to query Instagram posts with a particular hashtag.  It looks like this can be done with @mentions, but don't a way to do it with #hashtags.  Am I missing something?  I'm not sure if I want to get all posts with a hashtag or just authenticated users posts with that hashtag.  But when somebody posts with this #hashtag, I need to get the new post.  Is there any way to do this with the Instagram API?

I guess my plan B could be to create an instagram user and have people @mention the user instead of using hashtags.  Then my app could be authenticated as that user and do regular polling.

Answer (score 6):

Following is one way to do this:

`https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/<tag>/?__a=1`

but this is completely unofficial and instagram can change above api without any notice at any time.

for example; to search posts with #stackoverflow

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/stackoverflow/?__a=1

more info about pagination and other detail at the question and answer here:  [Instagram ?__a=1 url not working anymore & problems with graphql/query to get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265339/instagram-a-1-url-not-working-anymore-problems-with-graphql-query-to-get-da/49341049#49341049)

Also under item 10 of [Instagram Terms of Use](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511) - General Conditions: "We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos."

Comment: Thank you.  If there was a way to tell instagram to "push" content when a user has authorized it that would prevent any need for scraping.  Using this explore endpoint does definitely seem to violate their policy.  I may need to have the users log in to my app to refresh their instagram posts to my app, which falls within their TOC but just won't be as user friendly as I thought.

Comment: push is there for owned content via fb graph api webhook, but not for hashtags

Comment: `but this is completely unofficial and instagram can change above api without any notice at any time.` even their old OFFICIAL api was changed without notice last year.  After reading their review requirements for the new Graph API usage, they're obviously do not care about API integration for common developers and only for very specific use case, most likely for advertisers to get information on ads they've purchased on Instagram.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as of August 2023. Shows this error:
`for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":....}}},"lid":"...."}`