# I can't parse json from Instagram api

Tags: android, json, parsing

**I can not parse json from instagram api and my code has this error:**

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: 
Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Instagram API Link:

https://www.instagram.com/pr.rezaabiri/?__a=1

this is my code for JSON parsing:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new
JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, response - > {
    try {

        JSONObject graphql = response.getJSONObject("graphql");
        JSONObject user = graphql.getJSONObject("user");
        JSONObject edge_followed_by = user.getJSONObject("edge_followed_by");
        JSONObject edge_follow = user.getJSONObject("edge_follow");
        JSONObject edge_owner_to_timeline_media = user.getJSONObject("edge_owner_to_timeline_media");

        posts.setText(edge_owner_to_timeline_media.getString("count"));
        followers.setText(edge_followed_by.getString("count"));
        following.setText(edge_follow.getString("count"));
        txtAc.setText(user.getString("username"));
        Picasso.get().load(user.getString("profile_pic_url_hd")).into(imageProfile);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, error - > Log.e("err:", error.toString()));

jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 1, 1));
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: You are receiving HTML from that API request, not JSON. Make sure you are getting JSON from that API request before trying to parse it.

Comment: This code worked two days ago

Comment: Is there authentication on the API request? Are you sending along a valid API key or login credentials? Odds are that you are receiving a login page instead of the JSON you expect.

Comment: No it does not have authentication, it probably is as you said

Answer (score 0):

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019449

Adding a /channel seems to make it work.

https://www.instagram.com/pr.rezaabiri/channel/?__a=1

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;