# How to go back to past posts with hashtags in Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am an engineer.

I would like to look up past posts for a particular hashtag, but I can only reference the last 30 or so posts.

Is there any way to do this?

I have researched and found this thread([Instagram ?__a=1 url not working anymore & problems with graphql/query to get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265339/instagram-a-1-url-not-working-anymore-problems-with-graphql-query-to-get-da)), but it doesn't seem to be available at this time.

I would like to know if anyone can help me figure this out.